# org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "="

Tags: velocity, freemarker, xdocreport

This code works:

```
Project : «$project.Name»
Developers (Section) : 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
«#foreach($developer in $developers)»«$developer.Name»

«#end»
```

But this one not:

```
Project : «$project.Name»
Developers (Section) : 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
«#foreach($developer in $developers)»«$developer.Name»
«[#if($developer.Name='Angelo')]1[/#if]»    
«#end»
```

This is the code I enter into a word as a freemarker template, and the error is with the "if" clause. The error that flows is: Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "=" at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx.DocxReport@9affcf!word/document.xml[line 1, column 3211]

Can anybody tell me what happens?

Comment: I don't know velocity, but I'm pretty sure you need to use == to compare :)

Comment: When I change the "=" to a "==" then raises another error: Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "]" at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx.DocxReport@95bf4f!word/document.xml[line 1, column 3229]

Comment: Is there a reason why you are mixing velocity and freemarker syntax within your code?

Answer (score 3):

Well, finally I've seen which was the problem. I was ending my "if" clause with "". That's incorrect. The correct way to do it is just with an "<#end>" tag.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you need to use double equals signs like:

```
#foreach($developer in $developers) 
  $developer.Name
  #if($developer.Name=='Angelo')
   1
  #end   
#end
```

Also you don't need to use square brackets in velocity around operators.